# Deploy Angular 6 in Java WAR file

Tags: java, angular, jboss, wildfly, war

Is there any good way to deploy an Angular 6 app in a Java WAR file? Now, building the Angular app and copying it into the WAR file is not the problem. I though use routing within the Angular app and I build the app using ([described here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#simplest-deployment-possible)):

```
ng build --base-href=/my/app/
```

So how would I have to do this Angular routing thing in order to make it work perfectly within a Java WAR file, that eventually gets deployed on an application server such as Wildfly?

Comment: I faced issue after reloading app in routing to solve it I used hash true

Comment: @JayantPatil You mean what `J. S.` already suggested in his answer?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have an Angular app deployed in a war File. Routing works perfectly fine when you use Hash-Strategy: `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true })`

Wildfly even though struggles a lot without HashStrategy.

Comment: Am I understand you right, that this setting only has to be done within TypeScript? Are there no settings necessary within the WAR file? Just copy and paste the Angular dist?

Comment: Eventually yes. An application server serves the index.html within a war container by default and the rest is just business as usual, only problem is that without hash location the server tries to load a new application, when you just want to navigate within your app. It's like you said, after you build your app just move everything from dist into a war, add assets and (when needed) a WEB-INF folder with a web.xml. Also AOT works fine within a war.

Comment: What does AOT stand for?